# How to refresh session without logout/login on CentOS?

Tags: linux, bash, session, centos

I have a need to set automatic server preparation with increasing number of file descriptors.

Usual step is to change a system file and then logout/login and continue.

Is there a way to avoid logout/login and just continue within the same session or refresh/reload all variables as when login first time?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which file is modified and what is its purpose. If it's, for example a bash config file `.bashrc`, you can just source it:

`source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc`